# R ggplot2 boxplot order by 2 factors and assign colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data formatted like following:

```
name          site  numb  env        value     order1  order2 color
K_005_AllHuman  K   5     human       0.02941166    1   1   black
K_005_bacteria  K   5     bacteria    0.02941166    1   2   grey
K_005_oral      K   5     oral        0.02941166    1   3   blue
K_005_env       K   6     environment 0.02941166    1   4   green
K_006_AllHuman  K   6     human       0.02941166    1   1   black
K_006_bacteria  K   6     bacteria    0.02941166    1   2   grey
K_006_oral      K   6     oral        0.02941166    1   3   blue
K_006_env       K   6     environment 0.02945052    1   4   green
K_006_pathogen  K   6     pathogen    0.02945052    1   5   red
K_013_AllHuman  L   13    human       0.02928835    2   1   black
K_013_bacteria  L   13    bacteria    0.02870488    2   2   grey
K_013_oral      L   13    oral        0.02870488    2   3   blue
K_013_env       L   13    environment 0.0283742     2   4   green
K_023_AllHuman  L   23    human       0.0283742     2   1   black
K_023_bacteria  L   23    bacteria    0.0283742     2   2   grey
K_023_oral      L   23    oral        0.0283742     2   3   blue
K_023_env       L   23    environment 0.0283742     2   4   green
K_023_pathogen  L   23    pathogen    0.0283742     2   5   red
```

I want to plot the data in boxplots, such that boxes are forst ordered by the site name, within this, they are ordered by the numb column, and lastly they follow ordering of env column. Finally, I want to assign to the boxes colors as in color column.

I managed to produce ordering, but still the plot doesn't look like I wanted it to (no to mention colors, which get completelty mingled, when assigned manually, since each sample doesn't allways have all of the facto level of env column).

Here is the code I produced till now:

```
    c_df$name <- factor(c_df$name, levels = c_df$name[order(c_df$numb)])
c_df$site <- factor(c_df$site, levels = c_df$site[order(c_df$order1)])
c_df$env <- factor(c_df$env, levels = c_df$env[order(c_df$order2)])


p <- ggplot(data = c_df, aes(x = name, y = value, fill=env)) + 
     geom_boxplot(outlier.size=NA) + theme_bw() 
p + theme(axis.title.x =element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size =12), 
          legend.position="none") + 
     ggtitle("DeltaD") +ylab(expression(delta[d]))
```

Comment: change the argument `fill=env` to `fill=color`? For the ordering you can try:  `c_df <- c_df[ order(c_df$site, c_df$numb, c_df$env), ]`

Comment: You could use @Jimbou's ordering code `c_df <- c_df[ order(c_df$site, c_df$numb, c_df$env), ]` then create a factor of the `numb` column
`c_df$Numb = factor(c_df$numb)` then use an interaction in the fill `ggplot(c_df, aes(site, value, fill = interaction(Numb, color)))+geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the plot below, to get the desired ordering, I turn `name` into a factor after ordering it by `name` then `site` then `env`.

To get the desired colors, I use `scale_fill_manual` to map the desired colors to each of the possible values of `env`. Adding a column with color names doesn't work because ggplot doesn't get the color names from the data. Rather, it maps the categories in a data column to a default color palette that is the same for all categorical variables, regardless of what the values of those variables happen to be called. To set the colors to different values, you need to use one of the `scale_fill_***` functions.

Also, it looks like in the bottom half of the data the `name` should start with "L" rather than "K" so I've made that change. I don't think you need the `order1`, `order2` or `color` columns.

The code to read in the sample data is at the bottom of this answer.

```
# Bulk up data frame so that we'll have more than one measurement per boxplot    
c_df = rbind(c_df,c_df,c_df,c_df)
c_df$value = rnorm(nrow(c_df), 10, 5)

# Order name by site, numb, and env
c_df = c_df[order(c_df$site, c_df$numb, c_df$env),]
c_df$name = factor(c_df$name, levels=unique(c_df$name))

ggplot(data = c_df, aes(x = name, y = value, fill=env)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=NA) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title.x =element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=12),
        legend.position="none") + 
  ggtitle("DeltaD") +ylab(expression(delta[d])) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey","green","black","blue","red"))
```

[image]

As another option, the plot might be easier to read with faceting. For example:

```
ggplot(data = c_df, aes(x = env, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=NA) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ site + numb, scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  ggtitle("DeltaD") + ylab(expression(delta[d])) +
  labs(x="Environment") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=12))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = c_df, aes(x = site, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=NA) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid(numb ~ env) +
  ggtitle("DeltaD") + ylab(expression(delta[d])) +
  labs(x="Site")
```

[image]

The best combination of faceting and `fill` choices will depend on what you're trying to show, whether or not there are lots of empty categories for various combinations of columns, etc. For example, your sample data has at most one `site` per `numb`, so a lot of the boxplot "slots" are empty in the second faceting example above, but perhaps your real data has more category combinations present.

---

Read in sample data:

```
c_df=read.table(text="name  site  numb  env  value order1  order2 color
K_005_AllHuman  K   5     human       0.02941166    1   1   black
K_005_bacteria  K   5     bacteria    0.02941166    1   2   grey
K_005_oral      K   5     oral        0.02941166    1   3   blue
K_005_env       K   6     environment 0.02941166    1   4   green
K_006_AllHuman  K   6     human       0.02941166    1   1   black
K_006_bacteria  K   6     bacteria    0.02941166    1   2   grey
K_006_oral      K   6     oral        0.02941166    1   3   blue
K_006_env       K   6     environment 0.02945052    1   4   green
K_006_pathogen  K   6     pathogen    0.02945052    1   5   red
L_013_AllHuman  L   13    human       0.02928835    2   1   black
L_013_bacteria  L   13    bacteria    0.02870488    2   2   grey
L_013_oral      L   13    oral        0.02870488    2   3   blue
L_013_env       L   13    environment 0.0283742     2   4   green
L_023_AllHuman  L   23    human       0.0283742     2   1   black
L_023_bacteria  L   23    bacteria    0.0283742     2   2   grey
L_023_oral      L   23    oral        0.0283742     2   3   blue
L_023_env       L   23    environment 0.0283742     2   4   green
L_023_pathogen  L   23    pathogen    0.0283742     2   5   red",
                header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```